# Convert centimeters (cm) into feets and inches using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to convert centimeters into feets and inches using PHP.

This is function I use for this calculation.

```
function getMeasurements($cm) {

    $inches = ceil($cm/2.54);
    $feet = floor(($inches/12));
    $measurement = $feet."' ".($inches%12).'"';

    return $measurement;
}
```

I am calling this function like this :

```
$cm = 185;
echo "My Height = ".getMeasurements($cm);
```

Problem is after calling this I can get a result like this-

> My Height = 6' 73"

look at inches. Its incorrect. can anybody tell me whats the reason to get such a result.

Thank you.

Comment: `$inches` is the total number of inches. Perhaps subtract the number of feet x 12 from it, first, if you want it to represent the remainder?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php  
<?php

function cm2feet($cm)
{
     $inches = $cm/2.54;
     $feet = intval($inches/12);
     $inches = $inches%12;
     return sprintf('%d ft %d ins', $feet, $inches);
}

echo cm2feet(162)

?>
```

**Output**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php
5 ft 3 ins
```

Comment: output is `5 ft 63 ins`

Comment: How ? do google https://www.google.co.in/search?q=cm+to+feet&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=5-RvVdHDOc-xuATcjoAY

Comment: Sorry my mistake... I used to http://phpfiddle.org/ to compile. It was the error.. my about coding also working for me

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is that when you run it on phpfiddle.org it is not a true PHP environment. To fix this on phpfiddle, you should add space around your modulus operator.